# Saving Photo in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am trying to do this the most efficient way possible. Think of Apple's built in address book on the iPhone - that's what I'm trying to copy here.

One entity, `Person`, and multiple attributes, but each `Person` can have one photo.

What is the best way to save a photo for an entity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best way for you to save photos or any large data in my opinion is save them to a file and store the file path as string in the core data entity...

Comment: If you have to support 4.x devices, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

There's a great new way to store binary data with Core Data in iOS 5.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7+. `NSAttributeDescription` now has a `BOOL` property called `allowsExternalStorage`.

From the documentation...

> If this value is YES, the corresponding attribute may be stored in a
>   file external to the persistent store itself.

This means that binary data will be persisted to the disk and a reference to that item will be stored in the persistent store automatically by Core Data. In the Xcode model editor, this can be enabled by simply checking the option in the inspector view for that attribute.

[image: NSAttributeDescription Inspector - Allows External Storage]

---

For versions before 5.0, you will need to save the image off to the user's Documents directory, and then add a file URL to your model object before saving.

Answer (score 1):

In your managed object model file (.momd) in XCode, add an attribute to the Person entity and set it's type to "Transformable". In a transformable attribute, you can store any type of object which conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol and luckily, `UIImage` is one of those.
For more information about NSCoding, see the Apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding