# Saving a photo and showing it using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Today in my Application I am working on, it allows the user to Add a Profile Photo but I need it to be saved in Core Data, each time I think I am saving it it doesn't appear. My Code is listed Below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Associate", @"Part-Time", @"Area", @"Regional Cross Checker", @"National Cross Checker", @"Scouting Director", @"Front Office", nil];
self.PickerData = array;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.                                                                                                                                                                                   

if (self.device) {
    [self.scoutNameText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [self.scoutContactText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"number"]];
    [self.scoutTeamText setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"team"]];
    [self.email setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"email"]];
    [self.pick1 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick1"]];
    [self.pick2 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick2"]];
    [self.pick3 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick3"]];
    [self.pick4 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick4"]];
    [self.pick5 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick5"]];
    [self.pick6 setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"pick6"]];
    [self.jobtitle setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"jobtitle"]];
    _photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.device valueForKey:@"photo"]];

}

}


- (IBAction)ProfilePhoto:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
_image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
_imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);
[_photo setImage:_image];

//NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
//[self.device setValue:self.scoutNameText.text forKey:@"name"];
//[self.device setValue:self.imageData forKey:@"photo"];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

// Update existing device
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutNameText.text forKey:@"name"];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutContactText.text forKey:@"number"];
[self.device setValue:self.scoutTeamText.text forKey:@"team"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick1.text forKey:@"pick1"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick2.text forKey:@"pick2"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick3.text forKey:@"pick3"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick4.text forKey:@"pick4"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick5.text forKey:@"pick5"];
[self.device setValue:self.pick6.text forKey:@"pick6"];
[self.device setValue:self.email.text forKey:@"email"];
[self.device setValue:self.jobtitle.text forKey:@"jobtitle"];
[self.device setValue:_imageData forKey:@"photo"];



 NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

If you request to see anything else I will be more than Happy. Thanks for all of your dedicated support.

Comment: First, you should format your code and put only the relevenat parts. In addition, what about your model? Are you sure the photo is saved? Thanks.

Comment: my suggestion is save the image in document directory and save its path in core data. when ever you want to show the image retrieve it from document directory using the path from core data and show it.(reason:image Data will be very huge. your DB size will increase a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a large number of questions on StackOverflow that discuss how to save photos and using Core Data.

[Saving Photo in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539788/saving-photo-in-core-data?rq=1)

Is the one that comes up right away.  However, I question whether you have done basic debugging:

1. Is `__imageData` `nil` when you save the `NSManagedObject`?
2. is `device` nil when you attempt a save?
3. How are you fetching `device` from Core Data after a save or restart?
4. Have you looked on disk to see if the entity or photo is saved?

Comment: Thanks Very Much I figured it out and it is now working